# Install Shield for CodeIgniter 4 without composer

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, codeigniter-4

I like using CodeIgniter because I don't need composer. However, I am trying to install Shield for CodeIgniter (Authentication and Authorization for CodeIgniter 4) and I don't find how to install it without Composer.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is mentioned in the documentation that Composer is needed, **but this does not mean that it is not possible to install it manually**.
**You can install manually**, but this is **not recommended**.
I have provided instructions for manual installation in the link below:

[How to Install Shield for CodeIgniter 4 without composer](https://github.com/codeigniter4/shield/discussions/581)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed documentation you wrote! Finally I tried and used Composer for my first time. Now I am not sure if should switch and have CodeIgniter 4 be updated through Composer instead of manually.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need composer: from [Codeigniter Shield Installation Requirements](https://codeigniter4.github.io/shield/install/#installation):

> Requirements
>
> - Composer
> - Codeigniter v4.2.3 or later
> - A created database that you can access via the Spark CLI script

After Installation, you can opt between Command Setup and [Manual Setup](https://codeigniter4.github.io/shield/install/#manual-setup)

note: I'd also recommend to install CI4 with composer, at least for a clean installation on your local host. If your production server is a shared server and composer is difficult/impossible to run, you can create a clone from your localhost.

Comment: Why is CI4 better with composer than directly downloading it?
I started programming with CodeIgniter (version 3) precisely because it could be installed without Composer. I don't really like it (probably because I haven't used up to now and understood its virtues).

Comment: @user1314836 concerning CI4 installation, I didn't say it is better, but in my experience it is flawless and really easy to use composer on your localhost, while it might be a bit of a nightmare on a shared production server. Therefore composer install on localhost and then copy a clone to your production server to overcome those composer issues on shared servers.

Comment: How does it work? I download CodeIgniter 4 and I change configuration files, create models... if I use Composer, will it go to the "vendor" folder, and how will I create my app?

Comment: Best is to start from scratch, make a new composer installation of CI4. Copy your existing controllers, views, models to create your app. Then install shield, then config shield and write your code